# #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column. In my nginx server. (mysql mode)

Tags: mysql, nginx, yii2

I'm getting this error: **#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column**. I've gone through some posts that it is about **mysql mode** and did as they say. But can't deal with it. Appreciate any help. I'm using stuff: **nginx**, **yii2 framework** if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, you are trying to insert `''` (i.e. `varchar`) value in a column that has type `INT` and hence, it is unable to insert.

If the column is `nullable`, try inserting `null`. If not, you need to check the application logic and decide what the `default` value for that column should be. Once done, you can `ALTER` the column, add the `default` value and omit it from subsequent `INSERT` statements.

Comment: You say that every time when I insert to database something integer I should write some code in order to insert as integer???

Comment: Sorry @darshan but I just don't get that. The error message is clear, he's trying to insert a `null` value into a non-nullable column. He simply need to alter the table, as you suggested, to allow `null` values, nothing to do with `varchar` or strings. Or have I missed something here?

Comment: It is a bit confusing actually, as the error message quoted doesn't seem to bear any relation to the error in the image. I'm looking at the image.

Comment: @JoeMiller Yes, the message quoted in question says '#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column' wheras the screenshot shows different error.

Comment: @Sherzod you either need to specify an `int` value or skip that column. You obviously can't insert an empty `varchar` in an `int` column.

Comment: @DarshanMehta do you mean that I have to change **varchar** to **int** programmatically?

Comment: Nope, just modify your insert script and remove `bnomi` and `''` from columns and values respectively.

Comment: @DarshanMehta how about if I modify like `if(value == null) value = 0;` I worked.